# Bootstrap 3 nested column sizing based on parent column size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code in a template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-0">
    {{ COLUMN CONTENT }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-0"">
    {{ COLUMN CONTENT }}
  </div>
</div>
```

The template will be rendered in different contexts, and one of them will be nested within a column. So while I want to have 4 elements if the display is large (`.col-lg-3`) I only want this if the template is shown in a full container, not when is nested within a column.

Is it possible to have Bootstrap CSS decide the column class (`.col-*`) based on the available space instead of the window size? If not, how could I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least not in an efficient way.  You should use Javascript to determine the space and then decide which class to apply.